# Flutter: The System Cannot Find the Path Specified

Tags: flutter, build, apk, release

When I run this command

```
D:\Flutter\project flutter\navagat>flutter build apk --release
```

I get this following error

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Answer (score 8):

Check these:

- non existent directory/files under Path in your environment variables
- open `regedit` and check for `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun` and clear it out.

In my case I installed Anaconda3 and then uninstalled it later. It left a reference to a .bat file in Autorun that got removed and flutter or other software(e.g Android Studio) complained about it every time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how may sub calls it does (Gradle,Groovy,Java, Python), but it really works after deleting the value of an old Conda installation.